# How to Calculate percent in single query sakila format

Tags: mysql, sql

i am working with table `film` in mysql
The columns is `film_id` (primary key), `category` ( kind of movie), `Length` (in min)

I have to use `single query`, without sub-query and find:
for each category of films-percentage of films that are longer than two hours.

romantic-63%
horror-70%

I try maybe to replicate the column of id but it doesn't work

Comment: Could you paste what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to do a test run of this at the moment, but perhaps you can? Off the top of my head I'd try something like this:

```
SELECT f1.category, (count(f2.*)*100/count(f1.*)) AS percent 
FROM film f 
LEFT JOIN film f2 ON f1.film_id = f2.film_id 
WHERE f2.length > 120 
GROUP BY f1.category
ORDER BY f1.category;
```

Comment: hi, first tnx. i cant count f.* so i try something else but i have got everything 100% because when the contidion work, the f1 lines also go down                                                                                                    tried:                                                                                              SELECT f1.rating, (count(f2.length)*100/count(f1.length)) AS percent 
FROM film f1
LEFT JOIN film f2 ON f1.film_id = f2.film_id 
WHERE f2.length > 120 
GROUP BY f1.rating
 but got G 100.000 PG 100.000

Comment: i just got 100% for everything

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you cant use subqueries?